# Android: Get color Theme dark

Tags: android, colors, background, themes

I have created a menu in my application and looks white background. I want it to look with the color theme of black background. I have to change in the code to get it? I have declared this in styles:

`<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">`

**EDIT**
I not want the color black background. I want the dark theme that many apps have.

My current color menu

[LINK 1](http://sriramramani.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/pocket.png?w=400&h=311)

My whised color menu

[LINK 2](http://www.webdevd.com/wp-content/uploads/android-title-logo-tabs-menu-items-hidden.jpg)

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff000000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get from Android theme like this:

```
parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dark" to parent="android:Theme.Holo"
```

And from custom you can set like this:

```
   <resources>
        ...
        <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
            <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffff0000</item>
        </style>
        ...
    </resources>
```

Comment: change your theme from this my theme and tell what u will found after that

Comment: I have put in my code the colors current and whised. I want these

Comment: can understand what u want whatever color u want just paste it onto the place of #ffff0000

Comment: But there are apps with theme color dark and they have not android:textColorPrimary

Comment: from my edited ans it still not running dear can u rename or change style name MyCustomTheme from any whaere

Answer (score 0):

You can add a  in your style named "android:background" with black color.

Answer (score 0):

Better choice you must go with the theme black that will suite most for you So you will add the this to your mainfest file..

```
   <application     
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"
     >
```

And then you will get your desired dark black theme on your Applictaion

Comment: This code change the complete theme. I want change only color menu

Comment: You just set this theme only for your one activity only and then you can get this desired one